# how to turn on of turn off the ringing tone and vibrate tone in iphone?

Tags: ios, ringtone, vibration

the APP require me to realize a setting function,which can turn on/off the ringing tone and the same to vibrate tone, Is someone konw the answer?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[You should  Use `AVSystemController` for it.](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/source/browse/trunk/include/include/Celestial/AVSystemController.h?r=136)

```
[[AVSystemController sharedAVSystemController] setVolumeTo:10.0 forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me have a try!